Wrong font-size for long text in an HTML table, for Safari on iOS
I think I've almost minimized my test to as below (try to Run the code Snippet on your iPhone):


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <pre>AB</pre>
      </td>
      <td>
        <pre><span>A</span>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</pre>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Tested with Safari on iOS 17, it shows as below:

Removing the <span> will solve this problem, but I don't know why. Works on Safari for Mac & iPad.
Edit:
Adding a display: none; to first hide the <span> to make it normal and then toggle the display attribute won't let the font-size go back to what it is before, there must be something wrong with Safari.


Just to confirm that I do not see the problem on an iPad IOS16. But do see the problem in an iPhone SE IOS 17.

Seems to be a weird size adjustment specific to <pre> elements in table  <td> . I could fix it by applying white-space: pre-line; to allow line-breaks. See codepen: https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/dyEONJM

@herrstrietzel Yes, great, I see it fixed by adding pre-line. The code above is simplified from an editor that do not want line wraps. Thanks.
